# Special order on String with the power of Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, comparator

I've got a finite list (or array) of strings. This list shall describe my new order by the following means: A string `s1` is less than a string `s2` iff one of the next three statements holds

- both are in the list an `s1` has a lower index in the list than `s2`
- both aren't in the list and `s1` is less than `s2` by the natural order on strings
- `s1` is in the list and `s2` is not

I want to use the power of Java 8 to write a one line Comparator. What is the shortest such line? You can assume my list to be an `ArrayList<String>`.

Edit: I don't want to order the list I'm talking about. I want to use that list to define an order which allows me to order many other lists.

Comment: Comparator.comparing(is-in-list).thenComparing(lexicographic-order)

Answer (score 4):

The shortest `Comparator` definition you can get for your task is:

```
Comparator.comparingInt((String s) -> reference.indexOf(s)+Integer.MIN_VALUE)
          .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())
```

but it requires the reader to understand the `+Integer.MIN_VALUE` idiom in integer comparisons. It basically means “perform an unsigned comparison” (see also [`Integer.compareUnsigned(…)`](https://zgrepcode.com/java/oracle/jdk-8u181/java/lang/integer.java#L-1248)), so that the value `-1`, returned by `List.indexOf` for absent values, is treated as the highest possible number, so that every index of a present value is considered to be smaller than that, to meet your specification.

Then, you can simply chain another comparator, here the natural order, for the case both indices are the same, which includes the possibility that both are absent.

If you think that the unsigned comparison is to hard to grasp for the reader, you have to encode your three cases explicitly, as already shown in [tobias_k’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35180951/2711488).

Comment: That's a really nice trick I did not know before. However, if speed really is important, you should cache the results of the key function, otherwise you have to calculate the index over and over again.

Comment: @tobias_k: sure, there are several ways to implement a more efficient solution. This one here is only addressing the OP’s question for the *shortest*…

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Comparator.comparing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) to define the key function for the "is-in-list" comparison, and append a [`thenComparing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-) for the lexicographical ordering.

```
List<String> reference = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "blub");
List<String> toBeSorted = Arrays.asList("foo", "ccc", "AAAA", "bbb", "blub");

Collections.sort(toBeSorted, Comparator
        .comparingInt((String s) -> reference.contains(s) ? reference.indexOf(s) : Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Or maybe a bit cleaner, using three comparators, for containment, position, and lexicographic:

```
Collections.sort(toBeSorted, Comparator
        .comparing((String s) -> ! reference.contains(s))
        .thenComparingInt(reference::indexOf)
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

(Using just `reference::contains` does not work here; seems to see it as a `Comparator<Object>` then, instead of `Comparator<String>`)

Afterwards, in both cases, `toBeSorted` is `[foo, blub, AAAA, bbb, ccc]`.

---

Update: The problem with this approach is that it is pretty wasteful: For each comparison, I first check whether the element is *in* the list, then iterate the list again to find the *index*.

You can improve this by using the `index + Integer.MIN_VALUE` trick as pointed out [by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35182824/1639625) (if you like this, please upvote *his* answer).

```
Collections.sort(toBeSorted, Comparator
        .comparingInt((String s) -> reference.indexOf(s) + Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

This uses the fact that `-1 + Integer.MIN_VALUE` produces an integer overflow (or rather underflow), i.e. the result is not `Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1` but `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. In any other situation 'clever hacks' like this are heavily frowned upon, but here it reduces the complexity of the comparison by 50%.

But *if* speed is an issue, we can do better than that! Even with Holger's trick, the `reference` list is looped multiple times, at least once for each element in the `toBeSorted` list (and in fact much more often than that, as the comparator is not caching the values). If the lists are large, then it might be worth creating a hashmap, mapping strings to their position in the reference list, and then using that hashmap (with O(1) lookup time) in the actual sort.

```
Map<String, Integer> index = IntStream.range(0, reference.size()).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(reference::get, Function.identity()));
Collections.sort(toBeSorted, Comparator
        .comparingInt((String s) -> index.getOrDefault(s, Integer.MAX_VALUE))
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

So, instead of *2*n*logn* times (assuming nlogn comparisons with 2 indexof operations each), this will loop the reference list just once.

---

Update 2: Instead of manually precalculating the indices for each element in the list, you could also define a generic `memoize` function, caching each comparison key when it is first calculated:

```
public static <X, Y> Function<X, Y> memoize(Function<X, Y> function) {
    Map<X, Y> cache = new IdentityHashMap<>();
    return (X x) -> cache.computeIfAbsent(x, function);
}
```

You can use it like `Comparator.comparing(memoize(originalKeyFunction))`. You can use this for all sorts of comparisons (I'm wondering why `Comparator.comparing` isn't doing this by default).

For longer lists, caching the indices (no matter how) has a *huge* impact on speed:

```
# Items   Naive     Overflow   Index-Map  Memoize
--------------------------------------------------
     10      0.014     0.0048   0.0082      0.0085
    100      0.4016    0.3272   0.0566      0.085
   1000     50.29     26.12     1.15        2.7
  10000   6441.4    5595.2     18.2       151.6
```

(Measurements with N items (Integers) in reference list and twice as many in list to be sorted; each sort repeated a number of times (5-10000), showing the average execution time in milliseconds.)

Comment: Keeping in mind that `indexOf` returns `-1` when the object is not contained: `Comparator .comparingInt((String s) -> reference.indexOf(s)+Integer.MIN_VALUE) .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())`

Comment: Why using `reversed()` when a single `!` can achieve the same?

Comment: @Holger Right again; I was trying with `reference::contains` again, and in this case `!` was not an option. Anyway, I think the first way is clearer in the end, as in the second way you have to remember how boolean are sorted, which might not be entirely intuitive to everyone.

Comment: Still, using `comparingInt` resp. `thenComparingInt` is very recommended for `int` properties.

Comment: Nice addition. Unfortunately, I can only upvote once.